# Determine if a number can be made with prepicked numbers and times

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, .net, vb.net

I have 2 arrays one of the types of numbers that will be used and the 2nd array is how many times that number can be used. I have a letter that determines what kind of method will be used I need to figure out how many times I can use a certain number from an array to determine a letter+number The ‘number’ is what I have to make with all the available numbers I can use. If the number cannot be made I would like to just say number cant be made or anything but allow the program to move on.
Here is what I have

```
int[] picksToUse = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
int[] timesToUse = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };
string choice = Console.ReadLine();
string input = "";
if(choice.Length > 2)
{                    
     input = choice.Substring(choice.IndexOf("$") + 1);
}
if(...){
}
else if (choice.Equals("D")) 
{
     int amt = Convert.ToInt32(input);
 // code here to determine if number can be made with above choices
    Dispense(amt, timesToUse);
}
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript.

Comment: C# but has the same way of thinking to get it done

Comment: Are you by any chance making roman numerals?

Comment: No I am doing like an ATM?Cash Register keeping track of the bills left and if i run out of a certain bill so i cannot make the number entered i want to display cannot make

Comment: could you share a sample input ? D___ ?

Comment: Are you at ease with recursion? I think a recursive function with a boolean return could tell you if it works or not in a few lines, and then you would only have to worry about actually doing the transaction (or not).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=laV8vwH1N1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to finish my project.

```
 public static bool Validate(int amount, int[] total, int[] needed)
    {
        int[] billCount = total;
        int[] cash = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
        int total = amount;
        bool isValid = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < total.Length; i++)
        {
            if(total >= cash[i])
            {
                billCount[i] = billCount[i] - needed[i];
            }
            if(billCount[i] < 0)
            {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming picksToUse and timesToUse are exactly the same as you declared them, here's a way to know if you have enough of everything in stock to "pay up". It's a boolean function, which uses recursion. You would call it with the amount needed as parameter, and it would tell you right there if you have enough of everything.

```
Private Function HasCashInStock(amount As Integer, Optional index As Integer = 0) As Boolean
    Dim billsNeeded As Integer = amount \ picksToUse(index)

    If billsNeeded > timesToUse(index) Then
        Return False
    End If

    amount -= picksToUse(index) * billsNeeded

    If amount = 0 Then
        Return True
    End If

    Return HasCashInStock(amount, index + 1)
End Function
```

The `\` is an integer division operator (in VB.NET, at least - I'm shamelessly letting you translate this code). If you're not familiar with the integer division operator, well, when you use it with integer it gets rid of the floating numbers.

`3 / 2` is not valid on integers, because it would yield 1.5.

`3 \ 2` is valid on integers, and will yield 1.

That's all there is to it, really. Oh yeah, and recursion. I like recursion, but others will tell you to avoid it as much as you can. What can I say, I think that a nice recursive function has elegance.

You can also totally copy this function another time, modify it and use it to subtracts from your `timesToUse()` array once you know for sure that there's enough of everything to pay up.

```
If HasCashInStock(HereIsTheAmountAsInteger) Then
    GivesTheMoney(HereIsTheAmountAsInteger)
End If
```

Having two functions is not the leanest code but it would be more readable. Have fun!

Comment: I have a method so I get the number of bills I need and I also keep track of all of the bills I have left. I am thinking i need a method like :

               public static bool Validate(int amount, int[] total, int[] Needed)
                {

Comment: public static bool Validate(int amount, int[] total, int[] Needed)
                
I want to get better at recursion I will look at your VB and see if i can validate my dispense() with it

Comment: My code uses your array's index to looks recursively if you have every bill you need. It returns true or false. Once you absolutely know if you have the bills, you don't have to validate it twice, so you can just re-use the same method but this time change the code slightly so instead of counting the bills it subtracts them from your "bank" (and this method can be Void because you don't need to return anything, this would just be the "doing the work now we know we should do it" part).

Answer (score 0):

I got some working code. I did it with a class. I remember when I couldn't see what good classes were. Now I can't brush my teeth without a class. :-)

I force myself to do these problems to gain a little experience in C#. Now I have 3 things I like about C#.

```
    class ATM
    {
        public int Denomination { get; set; }
        public int Inventory { get; set; }
        public ATM(int denom, int inven)
        {
            Denomination = denom;
            Inventory = inven;
        }
    }
    List<int> Bills = new List<int>();
    List<ATM> ATMs = new List<ATM>();
    private void OP2()
    {
        int[] picksToUse = { 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1 };
        foreach (int d in picksToUse )
        {
            ATM atm = new ATM(d, 10);
            ATMs.Add(atm);
        }
        //string sAmtRequested = Console.ReadLine();
        string sAmtRequested = textBox1.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(sAmtRequested, out int AmtRequested))
        {
            int RunningBalance = AmtRequested;
            do
            {
                ATM BillReturn = GetBill(RunningBalance);
                if (BillReturn is null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot complete transaction");
                    return;
                }
                RunningBalance -= BillReturn.Denomination;
            } while (RunningBalance > 0);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Non-numeric request.");
            return;
        }
        foreach (int bill in Bills)
            Debug.Print(bill.ToString());
        Debug.Print("Remaining Inventory");
        foreach (ATM atm in ATMs)
            Debug.Print($"For Denomination {atm.Denomination} there are {atm.Inventory} bills remaining");
    }
    private ATM GetBill(int RequestBalance)
    {
        var FilteredATMs = from atm in ATMs
                           where atm.Inventory > 0
                           orderby atm.Denomination descending
                           select atm;

        foreach (ATM bill in FilteredATMs)
        {
            if (RequestBalance >= bill.Denomination )
            {
                bill.Inventory -= 1;
                Bills.Add(bill.Denomination);
                return bill;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```